# How to get data from element in array javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Hello I am learning JavaScript now. I want to insert point X and Y using event click on my graph into the database.

I'm using [this tutorial](http://devproconnections.com/html5/html5-tutorial-build-chart-javascript-and-html5-canvas) to create a graphic. and now I found the problem when I want to get coordinate from my canvas when I press click inside my Graph.

here my code in JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Canvas Chart Demo</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/canvasChart.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var dataDef = { title: "US Population Chart",
                            xLabel: 'Year', 
                            yLabel: 'Population (millions)',
                            labelFont: '19pt Arial', 
                            dataPointFont: '10pt Arial',
                            renderTypes: [CanvasChart.renderType.lines, CanvasChart.renderType.points],
                            dataPoints: [{ x: '0', y: 25 }, 
                                         { x: '1810', y: 70 }, 
                                         { x: '1830', y: 12.8 }, 
                                         { x: '1850', y: 23.1 },
                                         { x: '1870', y: 36.5 },
                                         { x: '1890', y: 62.9 }, 
                                         { x: '1910', y: 92.2 },
                                         { x: '1930', y: 123.2 },
                                         { x: '1950', y: 151.3 }, 
                                         { x: '1970', y: 203.2 },
                                         { x: '1990', y: 248.7 }, 
                                         { x: '2010', y: 308.7}]
                           };
            CanvasChart.render('canvas', dataDef);
        });

        $(function(){
            $("#canvas").click(function(event){
                var dataDef = { title: "US Population Chart",
                            xLabel: 'Year', 
                            yLabel: 'Population (millions)',
                            labelFont: '19pt Arial', 
                            dataPointFont: '10pt Arial',
                            renderTypes: [CanvasChart.renderType.lines, CanvasChart.renderType.points],
                            dataPoints: [{ x: '0', y: 25 }, 
                                         { x: '1810', y: 70 }, 
                                         { x: '1830', y: 12.8 }, 
                                         { x: '1850', y: 23.1 },
                                         { x: '1870', y: 36.5 },
                                         { x: '1890', y: 62.9 }, 
                                         { x: '1910', y: 92.2 },
                                         { x: '1930', y: 123.2 },
                                         { x: '1950', y: 151.3 }, 
                                         { x: '1970', y: 203.2 },
                                         { x: '1990', y: 248.7 }, 
                                         { x: '2010', y: 308.7}
                            ]
                           };
                alert(dataDef[dataPoints[0]]); 

        });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body style="margin-left:50px;margin-top:50px;">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>
    <div class="log"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you very much.
This is if you want to collaborate in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fatchul/6wgLxkss/#&togetherjs=NPCnP60gNJ

Comment: Please try to be more clear, is confused what are you trying to do.

Comment: Your javascript doesn't run. `"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"`.

Comment: Okay, I've edited my question

Comment: "jQuery get click position" - If you'd consulted google, you'd already have your answer

Comment: Yea, but my question is how to 'explode' dataPoints from my case above ~ dataPoints: [{ x: '0', y: 25 }, { x: '101', y: 225 }] into x:0 and y:25